# Creating 2D arrary using vector

Tags: c++, vector

I have been trying to create a 2D array of vector. Here is an example of what I am doing.

```
struct TILE {
    int a;
};

TILE temp_tile;

std::vector<TILE> temp_vec_tile;
std::vector<std::vector<TILE>> tile;


for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < 10; y++) {

    temp_tile.a = x;
    temp_vec_tile.push_back(temp_tile);
    }
    tile.push_back(temp_vec_tile);
}

// Why does this not work? 

int x = tile[3][5].a;
```

Can anybody correct me. tell me why it is not working.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"?

Answer (score 2):

You don't clear temp_vec_tile between rows, so it's just going to keep growing...

So instead of your row vectors all have 10 elements, the first will have 10, the next 20, then 30, etc. And the first 10 elements will always be those of the first row. So indexing won't get you back the elements you are expecting.

Instead of pushing back into a temp vector<>, and then pushing that into your outer vector<>, you could reserve the size of the vector<>s outside of the loops, and store directly in the inner loop.

Comment: JasonD can you please give a correct code for you explanation.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly isn't working? You may get somewhat unexpected values because you create an ever growing `temp_vec_tile`. You might want to truncate it after inserting it into the outer vector, e.g., using `clear()`.